# Custom error message processor without monkey patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rubygems

I've implemented a custom error message processor for Korean language. In Korean, postpositions take different forms depending on the sound of the preceding noun or pronoun.

For example, when marking a subject, **ka (가)** is used following a vowel and **i (이)** is used following a consonant.

Examples (hyphens are to denote morpheme boundaries):

```
Romanization: sakwa-ka ppalkah-ta.
Gloss:        Apple-SUBJECT red-PRESENT.
Translation:  Apple is red.

Romanization: phainayphul-i tal-ta.
Gloss:        Pineapple-SUBJECT sweet-PRESENT.
Translation:  Pineapple is sweet.
```

Therefore, the standard error message system implemented in ActiveModel::Errors is not adequate for Korean. You should either include the attribute in the message making a lot of duplicates ("A is blank", "B is blank", "C is blank", ...), or avoid postpositions after the attribute which is often difficult or makes awkward sentences.

I monkey patched ActiveModel::Errors and altered `generate_message` to solve this problem. Following is the code ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/3988479)) which is currently in `config/initializers` in my Rails app.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# Original article: http://dailyupgrade.me/post/6806676778/rubyonrails-full-messages-for-korean
# Modified to support more postpositions and client_side_validations gem.
#
# Add Korean translations like this:
#   ko:
#     errors:
#       format: "%{message}"
#       messages:
#         blank: "%{attribute}((이)) 입력되지 않았습니다"
#         taken: "이미 사용 중인 %{attribute}입니다"
#         invalid: "잘못된 %{attribute}입니다"
#         too_short: "%{attribute}((이)) 너무 짧습니다"
#

class Korean

  POSTPOSITIONS = {"은" => "는", "이" => "가", "을" => "를", "과" => "와", "으로" => "로"}

  def self.select_postposition(last_letter, postposition)
    return postposition unless last_letter >= "가" && last_letter <= "힣"
    final = last_letter.mb_chars.last.decompose[2]
    if final.nil?
      # 받침 없음
      POSTPOSITIONS[postposition] || postposition
    elsif final == "ㄹ" && (postposition == "으로" || postposition == "로")
      # 'ㄹ 받침 + (으)로'를 위한 특별 규칙
      "로"
    else
      # 받침 있음
      POSTPOSITIONS.invert[postposition] || postposition
    end
  end
end

module ActiveModel

  class Errors

    old_generate_message = instance_method("generate_message")

    define_method("generate_message") do |attribute, type = :invalid, options = {}|
      msg = old_generate_message.bind(self).(attribute, type, options)
      return msg unless I18n.locale == :ko
      msg.gsub(/(?<=(.{1}))\(\((은|는|이|가|을|를|과|와|으로|로)\)\)/) do
        Korean.select_postposition $1, $2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My first question is whether it is possible to achieve the same goal without monkey patching. I'm new to Rails (and Ruby too) so couldn't come up with a better solution.

The second question is about extracting this code from my Rails app and making it into a separate gem. I'm cutting my teeth on developing gems and recently made [my first gem](https://github.com/clee704/virtual_attributes). In what place should I put this code in a gem? `config/initializers` doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at ruby but the following javascript code do the same thing. I hope it may help.

```
var hasJongsung = function(word) {
  return !!(word && word[word.length -1].charCodeAt()>=0xAC00 && word[word.length-1].charCodeAt()<=0xD7A3 && (word[word.length -1].charCodeAt()-0xAC00)%28);
};
```

source:http://spectrumdig.blogspot.kr/2012/11/unicode-20.html